# Java Swing Application font loads as a jar but not in Intellij

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, fonts

I just upgraded from IntelliJ 14 to IntelliJ 15, and now my Java Swing fonts won't load.

I haven't changed any code since I last compiled it, and the program works fine if it is compiled into a Jar, but not through IntelliJ's Run command. I am using Courier as the font (My program needs the font monospace for alignment).

Any ideas why the font wouldn't load between the two versions or between the IDE and JAR?

For the sake of completion, here is the code loading the font:

```
output = new JTextArea(15,15);
output.setEditable(false);
output.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN,12));
```

P.S. I couldn't find any other forums that this would fit in, and this is the reverse issue of what I have found on other posts.

Comment: Where is the font stored?  How is the project structured?

Comment: Courier is built in to all OSes, so I do not have it downloaded separately. All the classes are in the root of the jar. There are no other resources. Also, it works fine she I'm not running it through IntelliJ 15 (14 and as a standalone). OS is Windows 10 Home 64-bit. JDK 1.8 u66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized since IntelliJ's runtime is separate from the regular system so that it can monitor and debug the program, it would not access the system fonts regularly (at least in this new update).

I worked around it by calling for a dynamic font, in this case `new Font("Monospaced",Font.PLAIN,12)`. It calls for the best fit font the system can access that is monospace.